# $JAVA_HOME is wrong, how do I find out what to actually set it to?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a program that I am trying to install on my ubuntu 20.04 machine. Installation of the program fails with this message

```
Java was not found in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212
```

This seems strange to me so I check my $JAVA_HOME (which I strangely enough, only can view as root?)

```
# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_212
```

Seems correct, I now try to cd to */usr/lib/jvm/*. Here I can that there actually is no jdk1.8.0_212 file or directory there. It would then make sense for the installation to fail.

So now I need to find my java installation and set JAVA_HOME to it. I have java installed by jdk:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

So now I run:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ cd /usr/bin
$ file java
java: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/java
```

Ok, cool so I just need to there to find the actual installation

```
$ cd /etc/alternatives/
$ file java
```

java: symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
redirected again, so I cd there:

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/
ask@garser:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin$ file java
java: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=3d504fb34d33700e2299eb7797d78751d2d0a126, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

And I have no idea what this means. How do I find the installation java that I can see when I type "java -version"?
EDIT:

I just learned that I also should be able to find my java installation by running:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/
```

This is a completely new path however, and I dont know what this means

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's nothing wrong setting `$JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/bin/`, as Java is indeed placed there. The fact that it is set as a link, should not make any difference.